# How do I get Sigmatel Audio working properly on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sigmatel

I recently installed Windows 7 RC on an Acer Travelmate 3002WTci and I've managed to get everything to work except the audio.

Does anyone know of a Windows 7 compatible driver available for download anywhere?

Comment: Do you have Windows Vista drivers already?

Comment: Darn according to the Acer site you model is not eligle to upgrade to Windows 7 (http://www.acer.com/windows7upgrade/eligible.html) which means I can't find the drivers there

Comment: Nope I don't have a vista driver, been running XP on this machine all the while. I tried a few vista drivers off the Dell website, but those didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to find out what model number you audio component has.

Since the Vista (and hopefully 7) driver [I found at this link](http://sigmatel-audio.software.informer.com/) only works for a couple of models:

> The Sigmatel AC97 audio driver is for
>   Windows Vista, Windows XP or Windows
>   2000. Technically, it is the rather long winded: Sigmatel C-Major STAC
>   9750 AC97 WDM Audio Driver. Whatever
>   way you want to label it, the driver
>   package installs version 5.1 of the
>   driver onto your system and can be
>   used as an update to an earlier driver
>   or as part of a new installation.  The
>   driver can be used for the following
>   Sigmatel models:  STAC 9200, STAC
>   9204, STAC 9205, STAC 9220, STAC 9221,
>   STAC 9223, STAC 9227, STAC 9228, STAC
>   9229, STAC 9230, STAC 9254, STAC 9255,
>   STAC 9271, STAC 9272, STAC 9273, STAC
>   9274.